# Links overlapping with the image in directional force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In my directional force layout [codepen](https://codepen.io/aa1024/pen/MBeRVa) I am using icons rather than circles; currently, the links are overlapping with the image/icon. I want the links to end just before the image. However I see in [d3noob's example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278) the link starts/end after the circle, it does not overlap with the circle.

I tweaked the following return statement but not able to fix it properly.

```
function tick() {
 link.attr("d", function(d) {
 var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
  dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
  dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
 return (      "M" +      d.source.x +      "," +      d.source.y +
  "A" +      dr +      "," +      dr +      " 0 0,1 " +
  d.target.x +      "," +      d.target.y    );
 });

 node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematical way to avoid this, without playing with the elements' order, is computing an offset, so the links start and end at the nodes' edges.

In your case, we first get the angle between the two nodes:

```
var angle = Math.atan2(dx, dy);
```

Then we compute the offset:

```
var offsetX = radius * Math.cos(angle);
var offsetY = radius * Math.sin(angle);
```

And finally use that value in the `d` attribute:

```
return ("M" + (d.source.x + offsetX) + "," + (d.source.y + offsetY) +
  "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + (d.target.x - offsetX) +
  "," + (d.target.y - offsetY)
);
```

Here is the code with that change:

```js
var width = 500,
  height = 400,
    radius = 8;

var fill = d3.scale.category20();
var links = [{ source:  "FH", target: "TP" }];
var nodes = [
    { id: "FH", x: 100, y: 110 },
    { id: "TP", x: 200, y: 110 },
    { id: "GW", x: 200, y: 110 },
    { id: "DB", x: 100, y: 110 }
  ]

var map = {}
nodes.forEach(function(d,i){
  map[d.id] = i;
})

links.forEach(function(d) {
  d.source = map[d.source];
  d.target = map[d.target];
})

var force = d3.layout
  .force()
  .size([width, height])
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .linkDistance(150)
  .charge(-500)
  .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var arrows = svg
  .append("svg:defs")
  .selectAll("marker")
  .data(["arrow"])
  .enter()
  .append("marker")
  .attr("id", String)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 10)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = force.nodes(),
  links = force.links(),
  node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
  link = svg.selectAll(".link");

restart();





function tick() {
  link.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    var offsetX = radius * Math.cos(angle);
    var offsetY = radius * Math.sin(angle);
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return (
      "M" +
      (d.source.x + offsetX) +
      "," +
      (d.source.y + offsetY) +
      "A" +
      dr +
      "," +
      dr +
      " 0 0,1 " +
      (d.target.x - offsetX) +
      "," +
      (d.target.y - offsetY)
    );
  });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
}

function restart() {
   link = link.data(links);
  link
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
  link.exit().remove();
  
  node = node.data(nodes);
  node
    .enter()
    .insert("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);
  node
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
  node
    .append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });
  node.exit().remove();

   force.start();
}
```

```css
#nodeConsole {
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  margin-top: 1px;
  overflow: autao;
}

#linkedNodes {
  width: 80%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 10px;
}

#srcNodes {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 8px;
}

#targetNodes {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 8px;
}

rect {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
}

.cursor {
  fill: none;
  stroke: brown;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
}
.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo, it is looking really great!

Answer (score 1):

In the `restart()` function draw the links before the nodes and use an image that has no internal transparency.

```
function restart() {
  link = link.data(links);
  link
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
  link.exit().remove();
  node = node.data(nodes);
  node
    .enter()
    .insert("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);
  node
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
  node
    .append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });
  node.exit().remove();

  force.start();
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't consider the fact that OPs path will be obscured by an image with opaque edges. OP can achieve the same as d3noob by either appending a circle to each node, defining a pattern for each image, and then applying the fill of the circle to that pattern, or by moving the arrow back: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajZrqj?editors=1010. The codepen I posted doesn't dynamically correct the positioning of the arrow, I manually entered the position.

Comment: I made the adjustment to have an icon with **no internal** transparency. I just tried it with a simple 16x16 png with an opague circle. If you closely at the used github icon the link is not visible on the black parts of the ico file.