# Best way to dynamically style svg marker elements

Tags: svg, d3.js

My question: Can svg `<marker>` elements inherit color from the `<line>` they are referenced on?

The background: I have a D3 graph that has different styled lines, and I want my lines to have arrows at the end.
So at the top of my `<svg>` I have `const defs = svg.append('defs');` and then further along I generate my defs using a generator function:

```
function makeDefs(defs: Selection<SVGDefsElement, unknown, null, undefined>, color: string, status: string) {
const markerSize = 3

const start = defs.append
   .append('marker')
   .attr('id', `arrow-start-${color}-${status}`)
   .attr('viewBox', '-5 -10 20 20')
   .attr('markerWidth', markerSize)
   .attr('markerHeight', markerSize)
   .attr('orient', 'auto-start-reverse');
start
   .append('path')
   .attr(
     'd',
     status === 'PUBLISHED' ? customPaths.arrowLarge : customPaths.arrowSmall
   )
   .attr('stroke', color)
   .attr('fill', color);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
makeDefs(defs, 'red', 'DRAFT');
```

And then I add the markers to my lines with:

```
 // d3 code to draw the lines etc
 line.attr(
 'marker-start',
 (d) =>
  `url(
    #arrow-start-${d.color}-${d.status}
  )`
 );
```

This all works great, my arrows have lines. But my current setup feels burdensome and clunky. I have about 20 colors and 3 statuses. With my current setup that would be 60 different:

```
makeDefs(defs, 'one-of-20-colors', 'one-of-3-statues');
```

My understanding of `markers` is that they *can* inherit color using the `currentcolor` attribute. Currently my `<defs>` sit up top underneath my main `<svg>` so any color inherited is inherited directly from that top level svg which is not what I want. The issue in my case is my `<line>` elements are the elements who's color I want to inherit, but according to the MDN docs `<line>`s cannot have `<defs>` as children, thus leaving me with the only option, of defining all my `<defs>` up front all at once.

Is there a trick or some attribute I'm missing here?

Any way to pass color to my marker when doing:

```
line.attr(
 'marker-start',
 (d) =>
  `url(
    #arrow-start-${d.color}-${d.status}
  )`
 );
```

?

For what is is worth, I'm currently wrapping all my `<line>`s in `<g>`. I suppose I could wrap them in `<svg>`s instead, and apply the `fill` and `stroke` there, and then define my `<defs>` per svg container? I tried this briefly and swapping the `<g>` for an `<svg>` broke a lot, but I'm not even sure if it would work, or be better for that matter.

Comment: [Coming soon to Firefox 111](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=752638)

Comment: Meanwhile, if I understand your question correctly, you'll need different markers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32964457/5768908

Comment: @RobertLongson wow great timing :D

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes, that is what im currently doing, was just hoping there was a better way